# Why my Loop is running indefinitly (sudoku puzzle related if it helps)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't figure out what's wrong with my first while loop. Is there something wrong with the `break` statement? Is there something wrong with my logic?

Running indefinitely:

```
function solve(board) {
    board = parseBoard(board);
    let holes = getEmpties(board);
    let i = 0;
    let l = holes.length;
    let counter = 1;
    while (i < l) {
        let hole = holes[i];
        let row = hole[0];
        let column = hole[1];
        let n = board[row][column] + 1;
        console.log(counter ++); // over 10000 and still going
        while(n < 10) {
            if (check(board, row, column, n)) {
                // check if in the same row, column, 3*3 square has the same 
                // value "n", return true if all 3 of them have no such value.
                // store solution
                board[row][column] = n;
                i ++;
                break; 
            } else if (n === 9) {// checked all 9 values
                // reset value
                board[row][column] = 0;
                i --;
            }
            n ++;
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

Running fine:

```
function solve(board) {
    board = parseBoard(board);
    let holes = getEmpties(board);
    let i = 0;
    let l = holes.length;
    let counter = 1;
    while (i < l) {
        let found = false;
        let hole = holes[i];
        let row = hole[0];
        let column = hole[1];
        let n = board[row][column] + 1;
        console.log(counter ++); // running 2203 times
        while(!found && n < 10) {
            if (check(board, row, column, n)) {
                found = true;
                board[row][column] = n;
                i ++;
            } else {
                n ++;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            board[row][column] = 0;
            i --;
        }
    }
    return board;
}
```

**Clarification**:

This is for standard 9*9 Sudoku puzzle.

Parsed board is a two-level array. Sub-arrays are rows. Each row(array) has 9 number. Empty positions are 0s. 9 rows total. e.g.:

```
[
   [0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,6],
   [0,0,0,9,6,0,4,8,5],
   [0,0,0,5,8,1,0,0,0],
   [0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [5,1,7,2,0,0,9,0,0],
   [6,0,2,0,0,0,3,7,0],
   [1,0,0,8,0,4,0,2,0],
   [7,0,6,0,0,0,8,1,0],
   [3,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0]
]
```

Holes are positions of 0s of the board. `[[row1, column1], [row2, column2] ...]`, e.g.:

```
[
   [0,0],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],
   [1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,5],
   [2,0],[2,1],[2,2],[2,6],[2,7],[2,8],
   [3,0],[3,1],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[3,7],[3,8],
   [4,4],[4,5],[4,7],[4,8],
   [5,1],[5,3],[5,4],[5,5],[5,8],
   [6,1],[6,2],[6,4],[6,6],[6,8],
   [7,1],[7,3],[7,4],[7,5],[7,8],
   [8,1],[8,2],[8,3],[8,5],[8,6],[8,7],[8,8]
]
```

Steps (back tracking, like a brute-force method):

1. Iterate through empty positions.
2. Start with value 1, check if it's valid.
3. If valid, go to next empty position. If not, increase the value by 1, check again. Until the value reaches 9.
4. If all 9 values are invalid, reset current position value to 0, go back to previous empty position, increase it's value by 1. Until the puzzle is solved.

Adding other parts:

```
'use strict';
function parseBoard(board) {
    return board.split('\n').map(row => {
        return row.split('').map(digit => {
            return + digit;
        });
    });
}

function getEmpties(board) {
    var positions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
        let array = board[i];
        for (let ii = 0; ii < 9; ii ++) {
            let item = array[ii];
            if (item === 0) {
                positions.push([i, ii]);
            }
        }
    }
    return positions;
}

function checkRow(board, row, value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
        let item = board[row][i];
        if (value === item) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkColumn(board, column, value) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
        let item = board[i][column];
        if (value === item) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function checkSquare(board, row, column, value) {
    var rowCorner = 0;
    var columnCorner = 0;
    var size = 3;
    while ((row - rowCorner) >= 3) {
        rowCorner += 3;
    }
    while ((column - columnCorner) >= 3) {
        columnCorner += 3;
    }
    var rowEnd = rowCorner + 3;
    var columnEnd = columnCorner + 3;
    for (let r = rowCorner; r < rowEnd; r ++) {
        let row = board[r];
        for (let c = columnCorner; c < columnEnd; c ++) {
            let item = row[c];
            if (item === value) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function check(board, row, column, value) {
    return checkRow(board, row, value) &&
        checkColumn(board, column, value) &&
        checkSquare(board, row, column, value);
}
```

Comment: Stepping through your code with a debugger will help you find the problem.

Comment: Never have used debugger (is it the debugger statement?). It's just that I'm afraid there is something wrong with my logic in the first code block. How can a debugger help me with that?

Comment: Why people are down voting? Can someone please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: The `debugger;` statement is one way to do it. If you're using an IDE you might Google how to use it for debugging. I don't know your developing environment, but Google should be able to answer all your questions. You won't regret learning how to use it. In the mean time, your question looks well written to me. Perhaps some people feel like your code isn't "minimal" as defined in [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, I didn't provide all parts because the only problem really is the while loop. Can you please confirm that my first code block's while loop logic is fine? So I can focus on other areas, like using debugger (I probably need to watch couple of videos for this). Thanks.

Comment: that break sure looks right. I guess you will see what the debug finds (alternately, you could also put some console.log action in to see if you are stuck in the inner while or the outer while). Actually, if that console.log is happening, break appears to be working or you would not keep seeing that message. There has got to be something subtle going on.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thanks so much for reassuring me that there is something going on. You are the only one who gives me a straight answer in my time of need. I took a nap, then found the problem. It's a logic problem and it's subtle. I am so happy right now. Let me write the answer down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem and it's a logical one.

This is what I did. I console logged the first 2000 board for each of the two functions. To see if there are any differences. The difference occurs at number 601th board.

The running infinite one:

```
600
[ [ 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6 ],
  [ 2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 7 ],
  [ 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ],
  [ 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0 ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
601
[ [ 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6 ],
  [ 2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 7 ],
  [ 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ],
  [ 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0 ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
602
[ [ 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6 ],
  [ 2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 7 ],
  [ 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ],
  [ 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0 ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

The running fine one:

```
600
[ [ 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6 ],
  [ 2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 7 ],
  [ 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ],
  [ 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0 ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
601
[ [ 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6 ],
  [ 2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 7 ],
  [ 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ],
  [ 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0 ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
602
[ [ 8, 9, 5, 4, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6 ],
  [ 2, 7, 1, 9, 6, 3, 4, 8, 5 ],
  [ 4, 6, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 5, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0 ],
  [ 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0 ],
  [ 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0 ],
  [ 3, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

As you can see, on the 4th row, 1st column. The infinite one doesn't reset the value 9 to 0 when there is no answer to the 2ed column. Then I take a look at the loop. It appears to be  that if a previous empty position value is 9, and increase it by 1 to 10, it will never reach the inner while loop, which means `i --` or `i ++` doesn't get to run, and `i < l` is always true indefinitely cause `i` is a constant number at that point.

Just add:

```
if (n === 10) {
    board[row][column] = 0;
    i --;
}
```

before the inner loop and it runs fine.

Comment: Well done! and welcome to the world of debugging. FYI: You should be able to mark your response as solved in a day or so.

Comment: @MrPickles Thanks for the welcoming. Yeah, I am so happy and pumped right now. How do I mark this post as solved? Is it done automatically?

Comment: it has been some time since I have done that. but there should be a tick or mark as solved button near the up/down vote arrays to the top left of the post. if will probably way (when licked) you can not mark you own post within X (days/hours). good luck :)

Comment: @MrPickles Just saw that, "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". Thanks and have a good one!

Comment: Outstanding! I still had to stare at it a while to see how you get to 10 without first getting to 9, but I get it. The if not found piece kicks in even when the while is never entered. It is a nice, well-framed question. You gave us all the information if we could just see it.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Yeah, that's what I thought too. It took me several hours and I didn't even see it. It's like my mind is fixed and just went through the same logic over and over again. That's why I bring it here, wishing more eyes can help me identify the problem. Thanks for helping.